# Syntax for returning array pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, return

**EDIT:** the correct syntax for declaring a function with the return type of **array pointer** in the example I wrote further below in my code example section should be as follows:

```
int (*my_function(void))[10]
{
    ...
}
```

Important note for future readers who might come across the same question: **don't** typecast malloc! Just don't. Thanks to user3386109 for that one. [Further reading on the *why*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Thanks to Andrew Henle and Eric Postpischil for their answers.
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) a *really* good explanation if anyone wants to read further on the the topic.
Original thread below:

***What* I want to know**

How to return a pointer to array in C.

***Why* I want to know that**

Because it (is?) should be possible to do so.

***For what* I want it**

To return multidimensional arrays from functions.

**"Have you tried structs?"**

Yes, but this isn't about structs. The point (no pun intended) of this thread is doing it with *pointers*.

**Code example**

My example is ***wrong***, thus the reason I'm asking here, but here it go:

```
int (*)[10]my_function(void) // Should be returning a type of array pointer to 10-elements array. Sure enough it's not.
{
    int (*ptr)[10] = (int (*)[10]) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Address of ptr is: %d", my_function());
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm not sure about how to typecast malloc to type array pointer to 10-elements array as well. If you know how, please let me know.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

As far as I know, using double pointers (pointer to pointer) in this case is **wrong**.
Code example:

```
int **my_function(void); // WRONG, afaik
```

*Rationale*: [this](https://youtu.be/_j5lhHWkbnQ) video, at 16:22.

I already tried searching online and in some books, they have examples using structs, pointer to array as function *arguments*, but not this.

If you have some knowledge about this topic, please reply, I'll be grateful.

Comment: *"I'm not sure about how to typecast malloc"*. Simple. Don't. [You should not cast the return value from malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: If you did do `typedef int tenIntArray[10];`, how many plain `int` elements from the start of the array would you expect `tenIntArray *example = ...`; and then `example[ 2 ]` to be?  Hint: it's not the third `int` element...

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you, I didn't know that. In the tutorial series on pointers I linked to, the instructor says to typecast malloc, so I just assumed it was the right thing.

Comment: @ward0 I haven't watched the video, but if the instructor was using MSVC, note that MSVC is really a C++ compiler with limited support for current standard C - it's not a compliant C compiler outside of 30-year-old C89.

Comment: @Andrew Henle He was indeed using MSVC, that might be it.

Comment: For the rare case where you actually need to return array pointers, it is better to pass them as parameters. In your case `void func (int (**arr)[10]) { *arr = malloc ...` This is slightly more readable than returning an array pointer (but still quite ugly).

Answer (score 3):

Arrays can't be passed by value, unless you embed them in a structure. When you pass an array to or from a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element. So the way to return a dynamically-allocated array is as a single pointer.

```
int *my_function(void) {
    int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    return ptr;
}
```

There's no need to specify the dimension in the type, as this will be ignored.

This is not a multi-dimensional array, it's just a 1-d array of 10 `int`.

The type declaration `int (*ptr)[10]` is for an array of 10 pointers to integers, not a pointer to an array of 10 integers.

Comment: *There's no need to specify the dimension in the type, as this will be ignored.*  That's probably a bit strong.  The certainly won't be ignored if the pointer is assigned to a pointer that's actually a pointer to an array, such as `typedef int arrayType[10];`.  In that case, dereferencing the pointer might not produce the desired result.

Comment: You can't assign to an array. Does making it a typedef change that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you misunderstood my question, and I'm to blame for that. You can *point* to a 1D array using a pointer, this way you can pass the array around from functions and to functions (as yourself said, arrays are always passed by reference). What I want to know is the syntax for creating a pointer of the **type** pointer to array, in order to pass ***multidimensional*** arrays around (returning from functions and passing to functions).

Comment: *You can't assign to an array*  True, among other differences. Hence my "might not produce the desired result" comment.  I'd personally never `typedef` an array unless for some reason I wanted to then immediately `typedef` a pointer that array for some crazy reason.

Comment: @ward0 *What I want to know is the syntax for creating a pointer of the type pointer to array, in order to pass multidimensional arrays around*  Read this: [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thanks! That helped a lot to clarify the topic

Answer (score 2):

`int (*p)[10]` declares a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.

`int (*)[10]` is a type that is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`. However, note that you do not need to cast the result of `malloc` in C. As a `void *` used as an initializer or right operand of assignment, it will be automatically converted to the target type.

`int (*foo(void))[10]` declares a function taking no parameters that returns a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.

Note that `int (*foo(void))[10]` can be derived from `int (*p)[10]` simply by replacing `p` with `foo(void)`. Generally, to get any return type for a function, write a declaration for an object of that type, then replace the object name with the function name followed by its usual parameter declarations.

Comment: Thank you so much, that answers my question. I came to lightly *thought* about using ```int (*foo(void))[10]```, but the [10] in front of the function seemed unnatural to me (kinda looks like declaring an array of functions lol), so I immediately discarded the possibility. Thanks again!